# Access ui pointer from a library (DLL) function

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qlibrary

hi all i want to update ui from a non member function. Any help other than passing 'this' pointer as my non member is a callback from library.

Below is my code :

mainwindow.cpp

```
static void callback(QString result) 
{
ui->textBrowser->append(result);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
int a=1,b=2;
QLibrary myLib("myaddlib");
myLib.load();
add = (myadd)myLib.resolve("add_function");
add(callback, a, b);
}
```

So all I need is I should be able to append data to UI from my non member callback. Please help me.

EDIT: i am not permitted to modify my callback

EDIT based on comment: `callback` will be called in a different thread, so calling a widget method from there gives error `'cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread'`

Comment: Be sure to only update the UI from the UI (=main) thread.

Comment: hi @JohannesS. I agree with your point but any solution for my case where i want to update UI from a library callback?

Comment: Can you modify the callback signature? For callbacks, it's usually helpful to be able to pass an additional pointer (usually `void*` that then needs to be cast appropriately).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating QT Ui with different source files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694474/manipulating-qt-ui-with-different-source-files)

Comment: Probably your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694474/manipulating-qt-ui-with-different-source-files). Friend keyword is the way.

Comment: `Ui::MainWindow * ui` can be a public member, or you can use the `friend` keyword

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji friend cannot be set to a member. However i tried to create global pointer Ui::MainWindow *myui and assigned myui to ui in the constructor but it throws me following error : 'cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread'.

Comment: Based on comment, this question has `callback` call in a different thread, so linked question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the things  worked for me which were mentioned here. 
Solved it by creating a dummy Qobject which has a public function to send signal to mainwindow. Create an instance of this dummy qobject and call the public function inside my callback.

PS: I have a limitation not to modify my callback hence the above solution.

Answer (score 2):

Going by your comment

> "i tried to create global pointer Ui::MainWindow *myui and assigned
>   myui to ui in the constructor but it throws me following error :
>   'cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread'."

Problem is, your `callback` gets called in the wrong thread. Here's one solution:

1. Create global pointer to the actual main window instance, let's call it `MainWindow *mainWinInstance;`. Also be careful that the main window instance will live longer than the library/thread for which the callback is for, or use `QPointer` if there's risk that `callback` gets called even after the main window was destructed.
2. Add following slot method to `MainWindow`:

   ```
   MainWindow::appendText(const QString &text) { // use const ref for efficiency
       ui->textBrowser->append(result);
   }
   ```
3. Change your `callback` to invoke that method using [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-3) using queued connection type:

   ```
   static void callback(QString result) {
       bool r = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWinInstance, 
                                          "appendText", 
                                          Qt::QueuedConnection,
                                          Q_ARG(QString, result));
       Q_ASSERT(r); // should only fail if there's a mistake in above code
   }
   ```

   Using `Qt::QueuedConnection` is impotant. It will place the method invocation in the event queue of the correct thread of the target object and return immediately. The event loop of the target thread will then do the actual call.

Comment: hi @hyde i tried ur code and i am getting assert error for r. Got no clue why it fails i mean no other error messages even when i debug. Any further help?

Comment: @NaveenkumarKattarathanaiah Then your problem is somewhere else. Here's a working example: http://pastebin.com/64bM7qXX

Comment: Are you certain `appendText` is invokable method? Did you remember to use `Q_OBJECT` macro in the .h file, and run *qmake*, and all the other stuff needed to make Qt meta object system work?

Comment: hi @hyde Q_OBJECT macro is present and i had run qmake still the same. It says "QObject::killTimers: timers cannot be stopped from another thread". Any help? And my 'appendText' is a public member function in Mainwindow class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an interface in a separate header:

```
itextbrowseraccessor.h

class ITextBrowserAccessor
{
public:
  void appendText(const QString& text) = 0;
}
```

Inherit `MainWindow` from `ITextBrowserAccessor` and implement the method:

```
void MainWindow::appendText(const QString& text)
{
   ui->textBrowser->append(text);
}
```

Include `itextbrowseraccessor.h` in your library source file. Pass a pointer to the interface to the callback.

```
static void callback(ITextBrowserAccessor* accessor, QString result) 
{
  accessor->appendText(result);
}
```

Comment: hi @Ezee thanks for ur quick reply, as per your solution I have to modify my library call add_function to accept one more perameter which I am not permitted. Any other solution.

Comment: So you need to specify in your question what other restrictions do you have. What can you modify? Body of add_function? MainWindow? What about creating a setter for the interface in the library?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the main window using `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()`.

Once you have found the main window, use `mainWindow->findChild<QTextBrowser*>()` to find the browser widget and then modify its content as you need.

EDIT:
example:

```
Q_ASSERT(QApplication::topLevelWidgets() == 1);
QWidget* mainWindow = QApplication::topLevelWidgets().first();
QTextEditor* editor = mainWindow->findChild<QTextBrowser*>();
Q_ASSERT(editor != NULL);
editor->append(QLatin1String("abc"));
```

Comment: QWidget *mywidget;
    mywidget = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
    mywidget->mainwindow->ui->textBrowser->append("something"); @Ezee itried above but didnot work out. Can you provide some correct sample code how to get mainwindow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @Ezee i am getting assertion error. And moreover i am having multiple text browsers in my mainwindow, how do i get to choose one  particular? EDIT: If i comment that assert line and debug below is the error i m getting "the inferior stopped because it triggered an exeption". Any help here?

Comment: Which assert happens? if the first one, look what is returned by `topLevelWidgets`. To choose a right editor you can use an argument of `findChild`: `findChild<QTextBrowser*>(objectName)` where `objectName` can be set to an editor in `Qt Designer` or in code wich `setObjectName`.

Comment: 'topLevelWidgets' returns mainwindow address, things ar fine until here. Now when i did this     QTextEdit* editor = mainWindow->findChild<QTextBrowser*>(readtag_textBrowser); it throws compiler error     'readtag_textBrowser' is undeclared identifier. 'readtag_textBrowser' is my object name where i want to edit.

Comment: hi @Ezee getting error "cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread". So Qt is running my callback in different thread and there is no way I can access ui?

Comment: Looks like the code in the library is executed in a different thread. I can't move futher without having a working sample.